# How to close iOS 14 DatePicker in Detox

Tags: detox

This must be super-simple, but I spent a bunch of time already trying to do it with no success.

After calling `setDatePickerDate()`, `UIDatePicker` is not closed and trying to calling to `tap()` on it throws an error saying it's not visible(why?).

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of research, I found out that you need to tap outside of the date picker to close it.

So the code to do it is: `await element(by.type('UIDatePicker')).tap({ x: -10, y: -10 });`